# Why can't I recast my concrete type as an interface

Tags: vb.net, generics, inheritance, interface, casting

I am looking to implement the ability to compare and sort classes in my model. All of the objects in my model will need some common functionality regarding to comparisons so I created an abstract `BaseComparer` that implements `IComparer`.

```
Public MustInherit Class BaseComparer(Of T)
    Implements IComparer(Of T)
End Class
```

Each class in the model has its own concrete implementation of `BaseComparer`.

```
Public Class PersonComparer
    Inherits BaseComparer(Of Person)
End Class
```

Then I have a `ComparerFactory` that is responsible for creating and initializing the comparers:

```
Public Class ComparerFactory
    Public Shared Function GetComparer(ByVal target As Type) As IComparer

        If target Is GetType(Person) Then
            Return New PersonComparer()

        ElseIf target Is GetType(Organization) Then
            Return New OrganizationComparer()

        ElseIf 'etc...
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

---

**The problem is that `ComparerFactory.GetComparer` throws following error**. Interestingly enough, the code compiles fine, but it only errors at runtime.

> **Unable to cast object of type 'PersonComparer' to type 'System.Collections.IComparer'.**

`PersonComparer` inherits from `BaseComparer` which implements `IComparer`. What am I missing here? Why can't it be cast? I suspect it has something to do with `IComparer(Of T)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your abstract class implements the generic interface [`IComparer(Of T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx), but *not the non-generic interface* [`IComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.aspx). These are actually two different interfaces, which are not related to each other, not even by inheritance.

You can simply have your abstract class implement both interfaces:

```
Public MustInherit Class BaseComparer(Of T)
    Implements IComparer(Of T), IComparer
End Class
```

Comment: I guess it makes sense that they are completely separate interfaces. For some reason, I thought they were magically connected somewhere. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

There are two different interfaces:

```
IComparer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.aspx)
```

and

```
IComparer<T> (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx)
```

The latter generic interface does not inherit from the former.

I would suggest making your BaseComparer directly implement the non-generic IComparer as well.

Comment: I wish I could accept two answers. Thanks for the help. This is what I was missing.